# Symbolizing Quantities in First Order Logic (FOL)? Did I correctly symbolize the quantities listed?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

**Domain:** D: {d1, d2, …, dk}: di: objects of the domain,
**Names:** N: {c1, c2, …, ck}, ci: constants/names

**Quantifying using the existential and universal quantifiers:**

- None (n = 0):  ~∃x
- Some (n ≥ 1): ∃x
- Every (n = k): ∀x
- Not every (n < k): ~∀x
- where: n = # of items to be symbolized
- where k: = # of items in the domain

**Quantifying using ∃ and ∀:**
Quantities to symbolize in FOL:
"at least 1", "at most 1", "exactly 1", "more than 1", "less than 1",
"at least 2", "at most 2", "exactly 2", "more than 2", "less than 2".

- At least one (n ≥ 1): ∃x
- At most one (n ≤ 1): ∀x∀y(x=y)
- Exactly one (n = 1): ∃x ^ ∀x∀y(x=y)
- More than one (n > 1): ∃x ^ ~[∃x ^ ∀x∀y(x=y)]
- Less than one (n <1): ∀x∀y(x=y) ^ ~[∃x ^ ∀x∀y(x=y)]
- At least two (n ≥2):
  ∃x∃y(x=~y)  At most two (n≤2): ∀x∀y∀z[(x = y) V {(y=z) V (x=z)}]
- Exactly two (n = 2): ∃x∃y(x=~y) ^ ∀x∀y∀z[(x = y) V {(y=z) V (x=z)}]
- More than two (n > 2):
  ∃x∃y(x=~y) ^ ~[∃x∃y(x=~y) ^ ∀x∀y∀z[(x = y) V {(y=z) V (x=z)}]
- Less than two (n <2):
  ∀x∀y∀z[(x = y) V {(y=z) V (x=z)}] ^ ~[∃x∃y(x=~y) ^ ∀x∀y∀z[(x = y) V {(y=z) V (x=z)}]

Comment: Not correct. $\exists x \land ...$ is not a well-formed formula.

Comment: And $\forall x \forall y (x =y)$ just makes everything identical to everything. You need to include in your schemas the predicate to quantify over to relativize the quantifiers: $\forall x \forall y ((Px \land Py) \to x = y)$.

Comment: Are the following quantities correctly symbolized now? I added in the predicates to make the formulas wff.'s:

• None : ~∃xO(x)
• At least 1 : ∃xO(x)
• At most 1 : ∀x∀y(O(x) ^ O(y) --> x = y)
• Exactly 1 :  ∃xO(x) ^ ∀x∀y(O(x) ^ O(y) --> x = y)

Comment: Did I correctly symbolize these quantities?                                                                        • More than 1 : ∀xO(x) ^ ~[∃xO(x)^ ∀x∀y(O(x) ^ O(y) --> x = y)]  
• Less than 1 (i.e., 0) : ~∃xO(x) 
• More than or equal to 1 : {∀xO(x) ^ ~[∃xO(x) ^ ∀x∀y(O(x) ^ O(y) --> x = y)]} V [∃xO(x) ^ ∀x∀y(O(x) ^ OP(y) --> x = y)]
• Less than or equal to 1 : ~∃xO(x) V [∃xO(x) ^ ∀x∀y(O(x) ^ O(y) --> x = y)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $P(x)$ is true for at least one $x$,

$\exists x:P(x)$

2. $P(x)$ is true for at most one $x$,

$\forall x\forall y(P(x)\land P(y)\implies x=y)$

Another equivalent expression, which is longer but maybe more intuitive,

$\forall x\forall y(x\not=y\implies \neg(P(x)\land P(y)))$

3. $P(x)$ is true for exactly one $x$,

This is the same as saying, $P(x)$ is true for at least one $x$ AND at most one $x$,

$\exists x:P(x) \land \forall x\forall y(P(x)\land P(y)\implies x=y)$

4. $P(x)$ is true for more than one $x$, which is the same as saying, $P(x)$ is true for at least two (different) $x$

$\exists x\exists y(x\not=y \land P(x) \land P(y))$

5. $P(x)$ is true for less than one $x$, which is the same as saying, $P(x)$ is true for at least no $x$

$\neg(\exists x:P(x))$

6. $P(x)$ is true for less than two (different) $x$, is the same as saying, $P(x)$ is true for at most one $x$
7. $P(x)$ is true for exactly two (different) $x$, is the same as saying, $P(x)$ is true for at least two $x$ AND for at most two (different) $x$,

$\exists x\exists y(x\not=y \land P(x) \land P(y)) \land \forall x\forall y\forall z(P(x)\land P(y) \land P(z) \implies x=y \lor x=z \lor y=z)$